# Boostrap datepicker + after inputbox it not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using bootstrap date-picker. I need to show multiple datepicker.

Html code:

```
<div class="content">
<input type="text" class="dateRangePicker" value=""/>
</div>
<div><button name="clone" value="clone"></button></div>
```

Js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".dateRangePicker").datepicker({
            format : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            startDate : new Date(),
            autoclose : true,

        });     
$("button").click(function(){
var clone = $('.dateRangePicker').clone();
$('.content').append(clone);
});

});
```

After I click the button the dateRangePicker clone will be append to content div.
Error: Append inputbox datepicker not working.
Expected : After append the textbox for all datepicker need to work

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `datepicker` as below to attach it to dynamically created elements:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3kgg6zy8/)**

```
$('body').on('focus',".dateRangePicker", function(){
      $(this).datepicker({
            format : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            startDate : new Date(),
            autoclose : true
      });
});
```

> **Note - If `$('body')` doesn't work for you *[there are possibilities]* then please use `$(document)`**

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are initializing the datepicker using the code

```
$(".dateRangePicker").datepicker({
        format : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startDate : new Date(),
        autoclose : true,

    });
```

You need to also call this code from your button click after the HTML has been cloned to initialize the new datepicker.

Comment: I used the same method its working but on dateChange event will trigger two times. have any other ?